# Firebase cloud function always getting null snapshot

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm experiencing some problems while testing my firebase cloud function in the interactive shell (`firebase experimental:functions:shell`). Within the `onWrite` event, `event.data.val()` returns null when I first call it, instead of returning the information I expect. Also, after that, it's not automatically called again after I change some data through a mobile app.

Here is a sample code:

```
"use strict";

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.syncMySql = functions.database.ref('/something/{user_token}/{something_id/}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data.val();
    const user_token = event.params.user_token;
    const mock_id = event.params.something_id;

    console.log(functions.config());
    console.log('# User: ' + user_token + ',\n# Something: ' + something_id + ',\n# Snapshot: ' + snapshot +  '\n Evento: ' + JSON.stringify(event));

    return;
});
```

And here is a sample of how I'm trying to call it from `firebase experimental:functions:shell`:

`syncMySql('', {params: {user_token: 'sOmEUseRtoKen1234-i_', something_id: '456789'}})`

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?
Also, what is this first parameter called in `syncMySql`? What's it's purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For invoking functions via the test environment like this, you need to actually provide the data that was supposedly written to the DB yourself.  `event.data.val()` won't read the data from an exising entitity based on the params, but will only return the information you passed in the first parameter of the function call.

For invoking `onWrite` and `onUpdate` functions you need to provide the data  in the form `{before: 'old_data', after: 'new_data' }`, where old_data and new_data can be primitives and/or objects, i.e. anything you would write to your DB.

So your full call should be something like this:

```
syncMySql(
  {
    before: null,
    after: 'something'
  },
  {params: {user_token: 'sOmEUseRtoKen1234-i_', something_id: '456789'}}
);
```

In this case `event.data.val()` should return `'something'`.

Comment: Ok, that worked for me to test that the `event.data.val()` returned `'something'` as you said.

Now, I have another question:
After a deploy, will this cloud function be called automatically for every token and id when something changes in the path? Also, the only way to test this for real, is by making a deploy?

Comment: Yes and yes (at least as far as I know)

Comment: Ok. Thank you! :)